# make: *** No rule to make target `main.c', needed by `main.o'

Tags: c++, automake

I'm just getting started with GNU Build tools and I've been trying to reproduce the hello world example ([Creating-amhello](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Creating-amhello)) with a C++ source instead of a C source.
However, I get the error indicated in the title. Below are the modified tutorial files I am using.

src/main.cpp:

```
#include <config.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  puts ("Hello World!");
  puts ("This is " PACKAGE_STRING ".");
  return 0;
}
```

src/Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([amhello], [1.0], [bug-automake@gnu.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another Makefile.am with following content:

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

Comment: I have a second Makefile like that. I didn't post it, because there is no changes in it when using cpp file instead of a c file.

Comment: well, I recreated your setup and after `autoreconf -if && ./configure && make && ./src/hello` everything works fine. What autotools versions do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 2.69

Comment: Found that is was due to a corrupted cpp file. Thanks!